# Vue Router: HTML5 Canvas image links won't route to the right URL

Tags: javascript, canvas, vue.js, fabricjs, vue-router

I'm attempting to link images on an html5 canvas to a url to navigate a site.

I'm using `Vue`, `FabricJS` for the canvas, and `Vue-router` for routing.

```
let computerClick = function (evt) {
  console.log("Computer clicked");
  this.$router.push('/app');
};
```

When the item is clicked on the canvas it runs this function, but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your example code within a vue instance?

Comment: Yes it's within a vue Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are defining a function this way, the `this` inside the `computerClick` function is not referring to the Vue instance and is thus `undefined`.

Not sure what the overall context is of your example code, but it would probably make the most sense to refactor your code to not define a function like that. I'd probably make `computerClick` a component method (which you would call via `this.computerClick()`:

```
methods: {
  computerClick() {
    console.log("Computer clicked");
    this.$router.push('/app');
  }
}
```

That being said, you can also bind the current Vue instance to the function like so:

```
let computerClick = (function (evt) {
  console.log("Computer clicked");
  this.$router.push('/app');
}).bind(this);
```

Comment: This made it work! I guess the .bind(this); did the trick! Thanks!